# Intuit anywhere - Open Id requirements and login questions

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I'm developing an application and I would love it to be in the intuit anywhere app center portal.
However, I'm confused regarding the open Id requirements.

My understanding is that I must be enable the users to have an account automatically set up in my application when they login through open Id. Right?

But what if I need more information than just email/name? For example, country? 
Is the recommended pattern to ask for the extra info right after the user logs in for the first time through open Id?

Also, what is the consequence if a user has already registered through my own application "normal" registration mechanism? Is that ok or all users must be authenticated through open Id?

You see, for my app, connecting to Quickbooks should be possible, however, not all my users will use Quickbooks, and so that should only be an extra option for users that have a Quickbooks account.

Thanks

Comment: P.S. This would be better as a support ticket to Intuit, since it's not specifically about programming. SO is for *programming* related questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that I must be enable the users to have an account
>   automatically set up in my application when they login through open
>   Id. Right?

Correct.

> But what if I need more information than just email/name?

Then you can prompt them to enter more information when they first sign in.

> Also, what is the consequence if a user has already registered through
>   my own application "normal" registration mechanism?

That's fine, you can log them in to their normal account then.